# How to hide the cursor on an image map area

Tags: css, html, cursor, imagemap, area

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sqghz/)

I'm making a web application for a touchscreen. This means i don't need a mouse on the screen!

I'm using `cursor:none;` to hide the cursor in the entire page, but somehow this doesn't work on an image map area.

each area is made as followed:

```
<area shape="rect" onclick="buttonPressed_DigitalKeyboard('Q');" coords="14,13,94,93" alt="" href="#">
```

The cursor does change to a normal pointer when i delete the `href="#"` but the href is necessary for the validation.

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sqghz/) for an example

Any suggestions?

---

[EDIT] I forgot to mention: i'm restricted to Google Chrome! (HTML5 FileSystem support and some other options i'm using)

---

[EDIT 2]

The Hack: Using a 1x1 pixel with an opacity of 1 that Greger mentioned doesn't seem to work either
[jsFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Sqghz/5/)

Comment: What type of touch-screen? Since there's no mouse, there's generally no cursor displayed so you shouldn't need to do anything.

Comment: @net.uk.sweet an [ELO TouchSystems](http://www.scansource.com/Products%20and%20Promotions/Manufacturer/Family/Product.aspx?pid=ELO-E700641)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/BaEks/

Add cursor:none; for area-tags

or:

```
* {
  cursor: none;
}
```

[UPDATE]

Use javascript instead of map/area-tags

Example:

```
$("img#appkeyboard").click(function(e) {
    var off = $(this).offset();
    var cx = e.clientX - off.left;
    var cy = e.clientY - off.top;
    if (cy > 17 && cy < 99) { // 1 row
        if (cx > 17 && cx < 99) {
            alert("button Q is pressed!");
        } else if (cx > 56 && cx < 202) {
            alert("button W is pressed!");
        }
        // ....
    } else if (cy > 114 && cy < 195) { // 2 row
        if (cx > 52 && cx < 135) {
            alert("button A is pressed!");
        } else if (cx > 155 && cx < 237) {
            alert("button S is pressed!");
        }
        // ....
    } else if (cy > 211 && cy < 291) { // 3 row
        if (cx > 90 && cx < 170) {
            alert("button Z is pressed!");
        }
        // ....
    }
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/RadVp/1/

Comment: This works great in Firefox! But i'm restricted to Google Chrome (sry i forgot to mention)

Comment: Ok, see http://icelab.com.au/articles/invisible-cursors-in-google-chrome-with-css/

Comment: Thats a really nice hack! But unfortunately it doesn't work on image maps :( See the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sqghz/5/)

Comment: Im afraid that you have to stop using map/area tags and make this in a diffrent way. http://jsfiddle.net/RadVp/1/

Comment: This works perfect! Thank you.
Add or change the answer so I can accept